# ScrollMagic doesnt respect the height of my div when resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollmagic

I'm working on a website using scrollmagic.
I have pinned a div and made a wipe with translate y, the problem is when I resize my window the section pin seems to lost its height and hide the rest of the content.

I believe it might be an error about what is loaded first

Here my site `http://eloisemonteiro.hol.es/` ,

I put also here the but the scrollmagic doesnt seems to work:

**`http://jsfiddle.net/5k2p88o3/`**

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your fiddle is, that the paths to your Libs are wrong.
Current: http://jsfiddle.net/yeEBa/jquery.scrollmagic.min.js
Correct: https://rawgit.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/master/js/jquery.scrollmagic.min.js

Modernizr was non-existent...
Correct: http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js

Furthermore there were scripts mixed into the HTML code, that were executed before the controller was even initiated.

Once you correct these issues your wipe seems to be working as expected:
http://jsfiddle.net/5k2p88o3/1/

On your other page I was unable to reproduce your issue.
If it persists I invite you to post an issue in the appropriate section of the GitHub project: https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/issues

If you decide to do that, please make sure to mind the support guidelines:
https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

take care,

```
J
```